# Web Push notification not working in Firefox Mobile after the app is closed

Tags: firefox, mobile, push-notification, web-push

- The application is hosted in Windows IIS server (version 10)
- The site is running in https with self-signed certificate.
- Tested on Android Mobile devices. (Samsung, OPPO, Xiaomi, etc.)
- Web push Protocol implemented for push notification
- The site can be ran either in browser or as standalone PWA.

**On Chrome (mobile):** After entirely closing the PWA and browser, the notifications still comes. Upon clicking the notification, it opens the PWA or browser and takes the user to respective page.

**On Firefox (mobile):** After entirely closing the PWA and browser, the notifications still comes. Upon clicking the notification, it does not open any PWA or browser. The notification was cleared. But it doesn't open anything. If a browser or PWA is still running in background (means the user is on another app or homescreen, while Firefox app or PWA is still in background), then clicking notification will open respective page.

Is this a limitation for Firefox mobile browser?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.